# Interchangeability of present perfect continuous and present perfect

Tags: present-perfect, phrase-choice, present-perfect-progressive

> **A:** Why is your baby's face so dirty?
>
> **B:** "He _______ (eat) chocolate."

I know the answer is present perfect continuous (*has been eating*), but what about present perfect (*has eaten*)? Can we use it in similar situations?

I'm interested in British English in particular.

Comment: I'd call it semantic, but it was not the fact that he has eaten chocolate (as in the fact that he has consumed chocolate), but that he was in the *act* of eating chocolate, and it is the act that generates the mess.

Comment: Please do not post questions a second time on the same site or on any other stackexchange site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm American, so keep that in mind. You can certainly say "he has eaten chocolate," but it would sound a little stilted or formal to my ear. I'd probably say, "he was eating chocolate."